# class not found error while running batch file (Java 6 environment)

Tags: batch-file

here I have a little problem:

I'm trying to fix some issues in a demo platform used by the company to learn about the environment. There's just a local module, created automatically with Ant using a build.xml.

To run the project is needed to run a local .bat file, based on command lines. Java VM is JDK 6.11. IDE: NEtBeans 6.5. Operating System: Windows 10 
In local pc I have the following structure:

```
/HostMng
         |- /local
                |- /bin / NodeMng.bat
                    . . . 
         |- /src 
                |- /hostmng / HostMng.java
```

. . .

Highligthted files are the 2 .bat files (based on cmd.exe format). Here's their description and content:

setEnv.bat ->  to set environment variables, automatically called from NodeMng.bat

-any problem here, already tested all lines and environment variables are set ok-

NodeMng.bat -> to run the project in testing mode. When I execute this file, I get the following error trace from cmd.exe console:

```
Starting HostMng...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hostmng/HostMng
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hostmng.HostMng
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
Could not find the main class: hostmng.HostMng.  Program will exit.
Exiting HostMng...
```

Here's NodeMng.bat file content:

```
@echo off
setlocal

title HostMng
echo Starting HostMng...

"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -Xmx500M -Dlog4j.configuration=HostMng-log4j.xml -Dapp.cfgFilePath=%APP_HOME%/bin/admin.cfg -Dapp.hostMngCfgFilePath=%APP_HOME%/bin/HostMng-admin.cfg hostmng.HostMng

echo Exiting HostMng...

pause
```

Comment:  at first, i don't include build.xml definition, as I suppose there's an error about path's call inside NodeMng.bat file.

Could you please hel me about this issue? If needed to replicate error or analyse deeply, I could include build.xml content or more aspects abvout the project that, maybe, could be in relation.

thanks in advance.

P.D: HostMng.java -with main() method- exists at \HostMng\src\hostmng\ package. Maybe there's an usage format that I'm not using correctly.

Comment: "HostMng.java -with main() method- exists" - but it's saying it's missing the compiled class file. AFAICS there's no -jar classpath provided either, so it's expecting the .class file on disk. Have you run ant to build this first?

Comment: Hi,  yes in fact it seems it's missing the .class file, under HostMng/build/classes this directory appears empty, so I also supposed the problem was there.... I'll check build.xml file as there can be an error there.  Thanks a lot   :)